# PHP json_encode not working with chinese character set

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, json

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=GB2312");
$arr = array('丂','亐');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Instead providing chinese character array, json_encode return null values.

Comment: Have you checked out any of the links on the right of this page?

Comment: yes i did but not found my answer

Comment: For me your example works fine. So I guess you are mixing encodings here. Make sure you input the characters using the default utf-8 encoding. Everything else will lead to problems.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014335/a-problem-with-passing-japanese-charactersutf-8-via-json-encode

Comment: Have a look at `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`. Available since PHP 5.4.0. `echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); `

Answer (score 3):

json_encode works with UTF-8 encoded strings only. If you need to create valid json successfully from an Chinese encoded string, you need to re-encode/convert it to UTF-8 first. Then json_encode will just work as documented.

Use `iconv` for converting encoding, you can also use [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php)

```
$str = iconv("GB2312", "UTF-8", $str);
```

Comment: if i convert it to utf-8 then i will lose Chinese character

Comment: Can you please explain your answer with an example

Comment: @Wasim See edited answer for converting encoding.

Comment: please explain with my example, i am not using string any where in my code

Comment: I have, understood about string but how about array. can you convert my code to working code?