# Cannot show Japanese in android when data is transferred by php through JSON

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I am working with a system which html code was set to Shift-JIS and mysql database was set to  `utf8_general_ci` as following:

ãŠè¿”äº‹é ‚ã„ãŸã‚ˆã†ã§ã™ãŒ
è¿”ä¿¡æ–‡...

Now, I have developed a php and android code to transfer data from php to android.
in php side,

```
<?php
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$user = $_POST['username'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `postcontents` WHERE id='$user' AND inside='0' order by date DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
array_push($result,
array('date'=> $row[6],
'name'=> $row[1],
'address'=> $row[2]
));
}
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

However, Json-encode in php file consider the information which is in mysql as rubbish data. Also, Json-encode may change the formant of the data. Therefore, I cannot show Jappanies in Android or browser. The output is null.

```
{"date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","name":null,"address":null}
```

How can I fix this problem?

By the way, I have tested

[A problem with passing Japanese characters(UTF-8) via json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014335/a-problem-with-passing-japanese-charactersutf-8-via-json-encode)

[difficulty passing Japanese characters(UTF-8) via json_encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051287/difficulty-passing-japanese-charactersutf-8-via-json-encode)

[Android Java UTF-8 JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318413/android-java-utf-8-json)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to encode non-utf8 strings using php 5.3.
Here is a comment on such behaviour: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#115733

You can test if you get utf8 strings from mysql via [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) function.

Also you may want to ensure utf-8 for strings coming from mysql: [How do I make MySQL return UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225013/how-do-i-make-mysql-return-utf-8) or convert encoding of your strings to utf8 via [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) function.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. When I have tested it, it does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using four suggestion from friends together

In php side:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'shift_jis'", $con);

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=shift_jis");

function my_json_encode($arr)
{
        //convmap since 0x80 char codes so it takes all multibyte codes (above ASCII 127). So such characters are being "hidden" from normal json_encoding
        array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$item, $key) { if (is_string($item)) $item = mb_encode_numericentity($item, array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'shift_jis'); });
        return mb_decode_numericentity(json_encode($arr), array (0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'shift_jis');

}
```

In android side

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "SHIFT_JIS"));
```